# Joining a table value function to a MSSQL query

Tags: sql-server

I have a table-value function that takes an ID number of a person and returns a few rows and columns. In another query, I am creating a SELECT that retrieves a lot of information about many people. How can I pass an id number from my main query to my function to sum a column and join it to my main query? I wish I didn't have a table value function since that would work easily, however, this function is used elsewhere and I'd like to reuse it. Perhaps this isn't even possible with a table-value function and I need to create a scalar one.

My main Query looks like this:

```
select id_num, name, balance 
from listOfPeople
```

And the table-value function looks like this:

```
calculatePersonalDiscount(id_number)
```

I would like to do something like:

```
select id_num, name, balance 
from listOfPeople
left join 
(
  SELECT id_num, SUM(discount)
  FROM calculatePersonalDiscount(listOfPeople.id_num)
) x ON x.id_num = listOfPeople.id_num
```

But you can't pass listOfPeople.id_num into the function since it's not really the same scope.

Comment: just in case you are still interested, you can join functions already, check my answer :)

Answer (score 51, accepted):

In SQL Server 2005 you can use the [CROSS APPLY syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156.aspx):

```
select id_num, name, balance, SUM(x.discount)
from listOfPeople
    cross apply dbo.calculatePersonalDiscount(listOfPeople.id_num) x
```

Likewise there's an OUTER APPLY syntax for the equivalent of a LEFT OUTER join.

Comment: This still works on SQL Server 2008 & 2012, and I can't imagine it "going away".  +1 for a nice concise answer to a specific question that I had to Google because I'd forgotten the syntax!

Comment: just in case you are still interested, you can join functions already, check my answer :)

Comment: Check my answer to Dmitrij's answer

Answer (score 1):

I needed this badly and you gave me the start, and here I was able to JOIN on another View. (another table would work too), and I included another function in the WHERE clause.

```
SELECT CL_ID, CL_LastName, x.USE_Inits 
FROM [dbo].[tblClient]
JOIN dbo.vw_InsuranceAppAndProviders ON dbo.vw_InsuranceAppAndProviders.IAS_CL_ID = tblClient.CL_ID
CROSS APPLY dbo.ufx_HELPER_Client_CaseWorker(tblClient.CL_ID) x
WHERE dbo.vw_InsuranceAppAndProviders.IAS_CL_ID = tblClient.CL_ID
AND dbo.ufx_Client_IsActive_By_CLID(tblClient.CL_ID) = 1
AND  (dbo.vw_InsuranceAppAndProviders.IAS_InsuranceType = 'Medicare')
```