# How to do function call in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, function, parameters

I have a stored function defined like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fn_IPO_Get_Elenco_Ipoteche 
    (@PAR_cod_utente INT,
     @PAR_cod_utente_sessione INT,
     @PAR_cod_profilo INT,              /*TODO: Da gestire in base all'esigenza del chiamante*/
     @PAR_data_scadenza_da DATETIME, --@VAR_Giorni_Check_From
     @PAR_data_scadenza_a DATETIME, --@VAR_Giorni_Check
     @PAR_considera_archiviate BIT)
RETURNS 
    @tb_return TABLE (num_prat int, num_ipotec int, tipoipotec tinyint, tassa_iscrizione money, datastipul smalldatetime, data_scadenza smalldatetime, data_rinnovo_ipoteca datetime, data_cancellazione date, data_autentica date, capitale money) /*manca CODICE_GARANZIA*/
AS
BEGIN
```

How can I make a call if I don't know the parameters' value? I can't make a call as

```
SELECT * 
FROM dbo.fn_IPO_Get_Elenco_Ipoteche(1234,1,1,'04/02/2021','04/30/2021',0)
```

because I have to take values from a table which contains these attributes

Comment: There is no standard for functions in SQL, each database does them differently, though  they of course have very similar functionality. You need to specify which database this is (Oracle, MS SQL Server, PostgreSQL, MySql, ...). Best way is to **tag** the database in question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Joining a table value function to a MSSQL query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/699318/joining-a-table-value-function-to-a-mssql-query)

Comment: By the way, if possible you should consider using an inline TVF, they are generally much faster than using multi-statement TVF like you have

Answer (score 2):

Use the `APPLY` join keyword:

```sql
select *
  from table1 t
 cross apply dbo.functions(t.id) f
```

That will evaluate the function for each row of `table1`.

As the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) says it:

> *left_table_source* { CROSS | OUTER } APPLY *right_table_source*
>
> Specifies that the *right_table_source* of the `APPLY` operator is evaluated against every row of the *left_table_source*. This functionality is useful when the *right_table_source* contains a **table-valued function** that takes column values from the *left_table_source* as one of its arguments.
>
> Either `CROSS` or `OUTER` must be specified with `APPLY`. When `CROSS` is specified, no rows are produced when the *right_table_source* is evaluated against a specified row of the *left_table_source* and returns an empty result set.
>
> When `OUTER` is specified, one row is produced for each row of the *left_table_source* even when the *right_table_source* evaluates against that row and returns an empty result set.

See also: [Using APPLY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#using-apply)
See also: [Example K. Using APPLY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#k-using-apply)
See also: [Example L. Using CROSS APPLY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#l-using-cross-apply)